# Using retrofit to call two APIs in same class

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am having problem while calling two different APIs. There is no problem while calling first API using retrofit but when it reaches second retrofit call, there occurs error. Following is my code.

```
//for first retrofit call:

apiInterface = ApiClient.getApiClient().create(LekhaDrillInterface.class);
    Call<LekhaDrillModel> call = apiInterface.getData(id, memberId);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<LekhaDrillModel>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<LekhaDrillModel> call, Response<LekhaDrillModel> response) {
            posts = Collections.singletonList(response.body());
            adapter = new LekhaBolpatraDrillAdapter(posts, getApplicationContext());
            rvLekhaDrill.setAdapter(adapter);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<LekhaDrillModel> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("error", t.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

here is no error and data is set in adapter

```
//2nd retrofit call

private void callRetrofitListData(){
        pariyojanaInterfaces = ApiClient.getApiClient().create(PariyojanaInterface.class);
        Log.e("memberIDIDID", String.valueOf(memberId));
        Call  <Data> call1 = pariyojanaInterfaces.getData(memberId);
        call1.enqueue(new Callback<Data>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Data> call, Response<Data> response) {
                datas = (List<Data>) response.body();

                if (response.body()!=null){
                    Log.d("jchhec","chekc");
                }
                itemListAdapter = new ItemListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), datas);
                rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
                rv.setAdapter(itemListAdapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Data> call1, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("error", t.getMessage());
            }
        });
}
```

the error is in the line

```
Call  <Data> call1 = pariyojanaInterfaces.getData(memberId);
```

and the error is

```
Unable to create call adapter for interface retrofit2.Call for method PariyojanaInterface.getData
```

PariyojanaInterface.java

```
 public interface PariyojanaInterface { @POST("projectBudget/pariyojanaListForMobile") Call getData(@Query("memberId") int memberId);
```

Can anybody please help me fix this problem?

Comment: share PariyojanaInterface.java code

Comment: @Radesh  public interface PariyojanaInterface {
    @POST("projectBudget/pariyojanaListForMobile")
    Call getData(@Query("memberId") int memberId);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you must change PariyojanaInterface.java to

```
public interface PariyojanaInterface {
       @POST("projectBudget/pariyojanaListForMobile") Call<List<Data>> getData(@Query("memberId") int memberId);
}
```

I Dont khow what your Data is, so you must replace `List<Data>` with `List<yourData>`

And you must change `new Callback<Data>` To `new Callback<List<Data>`